# Solving $x^2+y^3=z^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Solve $x^2+y^3=z^2$ in which x,y, and z are relatively prime and y is even.

I have done a similar proof for $x^2+y^2=z^2$; however, the $y^3$ significantly changes the method I used before.

My solution for that was

$x=v^2-u^2$, $y=2uv$, and $z=v^2+u^2$ where $u$ and $v$ are arbitrary relatively prime numbers in which one is even and one is odd.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264648/primitive-integral-solutions-to-x2y3-z2

Comment: Well the $y=2n$ so becomes solution to $x^2+8n^3=z^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Similar to problem I did before,

$x=2u^3-v^3$ and $z=v^3+2u^3$ where $u$ and $v$ are arbitrary relatively prime numbers.

However y is the value that must change since it is a third power. Thus rather than taking a square root I must take a cube root.

Therefore, $y={2uv}$

The proof was very long and tedious. It took me many hours to get, but if you check that parametrization it does work.

Comment: Isn't $y$ supposed to be an integer?

Comment: Does this actively solve as asked or just present a solution with out proof? How is the asker to understand if it is correct? Maybe it works for a few so?

Comment: Consider $x=y=3$, $z=6$. This parametrization does not cover all solutions.